# In which case meta's whatsapp payload examples will receive with multiple element in array

Tags: facebook, bots, chatbot, whatsapp

Meta's whatsapp API integration and response on webhook,

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/webhooks/payload-examples

I am new to the whatsapp cloud integration and I am confused why inbound message response of webhook is too weird with nested array, in which cases facebook(meta) will give an multiple elements in nested of nested array.
Is it good way to get entry[0].changes[0].value.messages[0].text.body or I require to add loop on every case?
What are the changes we will received multiple elements?

```
{
  "object": "whatsapp_business_account",
  "entry": [{
      "id": "WHATSAPP_BUSINESS_ACCOUNT_ID",
      "changes": [{
          "value": {
              "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
              "metadata": {
                  "display_phone_number": PHONE_NUMBER,
                  "phone_number_id": PHONE_NUMBER_ID
              },
              "contacts": [{
                  "profile": {
                    "name": "NAME"
                  },
                  "wa_id": PHONE_NUMBER
                }],
              "messages": [{
                  "from": PHONE_NUMBER,
                  "id": "wamid.ID",
                  "timestamp": TIMESTAMP,
                  "text": {
                    "body": "MESSAGE_BODY"
                  },
                  "type": "text"
                }]
          },
          "field": "messages"
        }]
  }]
}
```

Comment: The structure is already provided in the documentation, yes you have to access it through loop.

Comment: My dear, I know that documentation, also I had shared the link, my question is, is it necessary to go through the loop? because we are getting message text every time on first element, then why should we add loop.
What is the reason behind them, that they had added too many array instead of giving simple structure.
When we will get multiple elements?
I had checked documentation but unable to find any description of those array, what is the purpose of nested array!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the documentation of graph-api webhook, 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks/getting-started#validate-payloads

> Event Notifications are aggregated and sent in a batch with a maximum of 1000 updates. However batching cannot be guaranteed so be sure to adjust your servers to handle each Webhook individually.

You can also check the property-wise batch possibility in the provided link.